# Android Drag a View and change his Parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a way to do a drag and drop between a child view to a parent view. So I will put a image for better explanation:

[image]

Yellow represent a class that extends RelativeLayout.
Black represent a class that extends ViewGroup
White represents ImageViews
Red represents a View

So I need to drop White Blocks(ImageViews) on Yellow View, but I only drag over Black View, because ImageView has a BlackView like a father, so my solution for now is change father´s dragged view, but when I add a view on YellowView this cancel my drag event, so I need to continue drag when I change between Views. Note, there is a only way for WhiteView that is place on RedView, if Touch up and White view is far of RedView White block will back to BlackView.

So, i using this code I get from web:

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchDown(event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchMove(event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchUp(event);
            break;
    }
    if (aViewIsDragged())
        return true;
    return false;
}
private void touchDown(MotionEvent event) {
    initialX = (int)event.getRawX();
    initialY = (int)event.getRawY();
    lastTouchX = (int)event.getRawX() + (gridPageWidth);
    lastTouchY = (int)event.getRawY();
}

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {        
    if(positionForView(v) != -1) {
        movingView = true;
        dragged = positionForView(v);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private void touchMove(MotionEvent event) {

    if (movingView && aViewIsDragged()) {
        lastTouchX = (int) event.getX();
        lastTouchY = (int) event.getY();

        moveDraggedView(lastTouchX, lastTouchY);
        manageSwapPosition(lastTouchX, lastTouchY);
        manageEdgeCoordinates(lastTouchX);
        manageDeleteZoneHover(lastTouchX, lastTouchY);
    }
}
private void moveDraggedView(int x, int y) {
    ImageView child = null;
    View childAt = getChildAt(dragged);
    int width = childAt.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = childAt.getMeasuredHeight();
    int left = x - (1 * width / 2);
    int t = y - (1 * height / 2);
    childAt.layout(left, t, left + width, t + height);
    //TODO at this point if left less than 0, I detect part of view is out and I need to change this view to Yello
    if (left <0){
            child = (ImageView) childAt;
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
            cloneimage = new ImageView(getContext());
            cloneimage.setBackgroundDrawable(child.getDrawable());
            parent.addView(cloneimage);             
    }
}
```

So I think it´s a little dificult, but If any one help me change a WhiteView from Black to Yellow and keep dragged I will apreciate.

Thank´s!

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code that you are using now?

Comment: @FoamyGuy ok, I put a piece of code, If you need more information I will edit again.

Answer (score 0):

use ViewDragHelper!

here u can find the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html

Override ur onTouch events like this

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getActionMasked();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mDragHelper.cancel();
        return false;
    }
    return mDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mDragHelper.processTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}
```

then use the viewDragViewHelper

```
ViewDragHelper.create(DragCoordinatorLayout.this, 1.0f, new ViewDragHelper.Callback() {

                @Override
                public boolean tryCaptureView(View child, int pointerId) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public int clampViewPositionHorizontal(View child, int left, int dx) {
                    return left;
                }

                @Override
                public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
                    return top;
                }
}
```